# Append to a string with characters in a while loop python

Tags: python, string, append

I'm running into a problem which I cannot solve online- all answers I've found only allow the appending to happen once since it just keeps repeating the same action.

For context:
If a string isn't 128 lines long- I want to pad it out to reach 128. All padding should add 00 then move to the next line. For example:

```
01
01
02
03
05
06
09
01
```

Then with padding should become

```
01
01
02
03
05
06
09
01
00
00
00
00 UP TO 128 lines
```

Hope that explains what I need to do.

I've tried using .join and .ljust/.rjust. inside a while loop.
The while loop is:

```
while count != 129:
     padding.join("00\n")
     count += 1
```

However it only ever prints out 00. Any advice is appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Is using a while loop strictly required here as there's other and more practical methods to do this...

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `padding.join("00\n")`, exactly what do you expect this to do, and why? What does the name `padding` mean in your program? What do you expect should be contained in `padding` after the loop, and how would this help you solve the problem? What *is* contained in `padding` after the loop? Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: "Any advice is appreciated. Thank you!" This is [not answerable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236). Please try to come to your best possible understanding of what is going wrong, and then ask a *specific* question about that. It should start with a question word like "why" or "how", and end with a question mark (`?`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
your_string = "01\n01\n02\n03\n05\n06\n09\n01\n"
new_string =  your_string + (128 - len(your_string.split())) * "01\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to check the number of lines you need to count the number of "\n" occurrences. Since the string seems to be a variable amount you need to be able to do this dynamically. You would have to write a function to check this.

something like this should work

```
def pad_string(unpadded_string, string_length =128, pad_string ='00\n'):
    """Function to ensure that a string is ``string_length`` lines.
    Do this by counting the number of new lines and appending deliminator where neccesary"""
    
    num_lines = unpadded_string.count('\n')
    if not num_lines < string_length:
        return unpadded_string
    return unpadded_string + pad_string*(string_length-num_lines)
```

Using this in your example:

```
your_string = "01\n01\n02\n03\n05\n06\n09\n01\n"


def pad_string(unpadded_string, string_length =128, pad_string ='00\n'):
    """Function to ensure that a string is ``string_length`` lines.
    Do this by counting the number of new lines and appending deliminator where neccesary"""
    
    num_lines = unpadded_string.count('\n')
    if not num_lines < string_length:
        return unpadded_string
    return unpadded_string + pad_string*(string_length-num_lines)


print(pad_string(your_string).count('\n'))
>>> 128
```